# Running on python GDAL/OSGEO/OGR/OSR, trying to create a shapefile but get error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'

Tags: python, gdal

I want to create a shapefile. Here is my code:

```
import ogr, sys, os
import osgeo.osr as osr

line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddPoint(10,10)
line.AddPoint(20,20)

driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds=driver.CreateDataSource('test.shp')

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

layer=ds.CreateLayer('test', srs, ogr.wkbLineString)
fieldDefn_=ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTInteger)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn_)
featureDefn=layer.GetLayerDefn()
feature=ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
feature.SetGeometry(line)
feature.SetField('id',1)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

but when I run the code no shapefile appears on my desktop like I was thinking. It instead says on my console:

```
AttibuteError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your error is coming from line

```
layer=ds.CreateLayer('test', srs, ogr.wkbLineString)
```

Following upwards, that would mean ds has the value None.

```
ds=driver.CreateDataSource('test.shp')
```

I would check if ds is None. Perhaps it could not find the 'test.shp' file, a CreateDataSource returns None if that's the case.

Comment: What do you think would cause that?